# SFTP with a username AND login name?

Tags: ssh, sftp

I just set up a Mac to accept SSH connections. It need both a login and user name like this:

```
ssh admin@192.168.1.100 -l "My login name"
```

This works fine, but I can't figure out how to do this using sftp. There doesn't seem to be a -login option to the sftp command. Has anyone ever done this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's somewhat confusing that they use both terms, but login and user name are the same thing. Your `ssh` call only needs one or the other. I don't use Macs, so I don't know if spaces are allowed in Mac usernames, but you might try `ssh "My login name"@192.168.1.100` to verify that you can still log in. Similarly, for `sftp`, use `sftp "My login name"@192.168.1.100`.

Comment: Yep, worked as you noted, with quotes around the login name.